Number index to array element
Task
Convert number to Chinese Pinyin. Minus sign is equal to "fu".
key-value
# num: pinyin
0: ling
1: yi
2: er
3: san
4: si
5: wu
6: liu
7: qi
8: ba
9: jiu

Code
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char ipt[100];
    char py[10][6] = {"ling", "yi", "er", "san", "si", "wu", "liu", "qi", "ba", "jiu"};

    fgets(ipt, 100, stdin);

    int i = 0;
    if (ipt[0] == '-') {
        printf("%s ", "fu");
        i++;
    }

    for (i; i < strlen(ipt); i++) {
        if (i < strlen(ipt) - 1)
            printf("%s ", py[ipt[i] - '0']);
        else
            printf("%s", py[ipt[i] - '0']);
    }
    return 0;
}

Tested case
I inputed 600, the output is "liu ling ling". I have tested some other numbers, and all of them seems good, but the checking website said I was wrong.

Remember that fgets will in most cases add the trailing newline to the string. You don't handle the newline character '\n' in your code.

On a couple of other, but unrelated notes, first don't abbreviate names. Instead of ipt use input. That makes the code easier to read and understand. Same with py. The other thing is that all three clauses of a for loop are optional. You can have e.g. for (;;) for an infinite loop. In your case, the leading "initialization" clause isn't needed, so you can have for (; i < strlen(input); i++). Even better, I would suggest input[i] != '\0' as condition, so you don't have to call strlen(input) repeatedly.

@Someprogrammerdude But don't go too far in the other direction and make variables so long that they make it harder to read the expression as a whole.  Call it input (or line) instead of ipt, but don't call it previousLineReceivedFromUser. Also be aware of what conventions exist for short variable names. pt for point is way more readable than ipt for input, for example, and nobody is going to be confused by a loop variable named i (although I prefer idx for easy searching).

You've ignored the return value of fgets():
fgets(ipt, 100, stdin);

fgets() return a null pointer to indicate failure. Furthermore, fgets() include the newline in the input (if there's ample space). The simplest solution to strip it is:
ipt[strcspn(ipt, "\n")] = 0;

Now you can iterate through strlen() bytes like you originally were.
Except that you don't need to call strlen() twice at each iteration. Simply cache the value:
size_t ipt_len = strlen(ipt);

Now, the code becomes:
for (i; i < ipt_len; i++) {
    if (i < ipt_len - 1)

But as you're already using strlen(), you can avoid the strcspn() call and do:
size_t ipt_len = strlen(ipt); 

if (ipt_len > 0 && name[ipt_len - 1] == '\n') {
    name[--ipt_len] = '\0';
}

You can also simplify the calls to printf():
#if 0
if (i < ipt_len - 1) 
    printf("%s ", py[ipt[i] - '0']);
else
    printf("%s", py[ipt[i] - '0']);
#else
printf("%s%s", py[ipt[i] - '0'], i < ipt_len - 1 ? " " : "");
#endif

Or skip the whitespace altogether.
Yet you've failed to verify whether the input actually consisted of digits and a minus sign fully. At least some rudimentary checking must be in place.
Also note that the inner dimension of py:
char py[10][6] = {"ling", "yi", "er", "san", "si", "wu", "liu", "qi", "ba", "jiu"};

should at most be 5, and not 6, because the longest string is "ling", which has size 5.
Or you could use an array of char *s:
static const char *const py[] = {"ling", "yi", "er", "san", "si", "wu", "liu", "qi", "ba", "jiu" };

Additionally, the outermost dimension is optional and can be elided, because it can be determined automatically by the compiler.

The function fgets can append the new line character '\n' to the entered string in there is space in the corresponding character array.
You should remove it as for example:
ipt[ strcspn( ipt, "\n" ) ] = '\0';

Otherwise your code also outputs a string for the new line character.
And after that this if statement within the for loop:
    if (i < strlen(ipt) - 1)
        printf("%s ", py[ipt[i] - '0']);
    else
        printf("%s", py[ipt[i] - '0']);

should be removed. It is enough to write:
printf("%s ", py[ipt[i] - '0']);

In general you should check whether the entered string indeed contains only a sign and digits.

The checking website asks for an output without space in the end, so I wrote that verbose code.

The issue with your current code is primarily related to handling the newline character that is included when using fgets to read input. When you read input with fgets, it captures the newline character \n at the end of the input. This is why you're getting unexpected results. The newline character needs to be managed correctly to avoid interpreting it as a part of the number. Try something like this:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_INPUT_LENGTH 100
#define NUM_DIGITS 10

const char *PYININ_DIGITS[NUM_DIGITS] = {
    "ling", "yi", "er", "san", "si", "wu", "liu", "qi", "ba", "jiu"
};

void trim_newline(char *input) {
    int len = strlen(input);
    if (input[len - 1] == '\n') {
        input[len - 1] = '\0';
    }
}

void print_pinyin(const char *input) {
    int i = 0;
    if (input[0] == '-') {
        printf("fu ");
        i++;
    }
    for (; input[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        printf("%s", PYININ_DIGITS[input[i] - '0']);
        if (input[i + 1] != '\0') {
            printf(" ");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    char input[MAX_INPUT_LENGTH];
    if (fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin)) {
        trim_newline(input);
        print_pinyin(input);
    }
    return 0;
}

Example Usage 1:
600
liu ling ling

Example Usage 2:
-600
fu liu ling ling


Identifiers starting with an _ and a then a lower case letter are reserved at file scope. _trim_newline should be just trim_newline.

TIL was using python practice of underscore for "private" functions.



#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char s[100];
    char table[11][10] = {"ling","yi","er","san","si","wu","liu","qi","ba","jiu"};
    scanf("%s",s);
    int first = 1;
    for(int i = 0;s[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        if(i == 0 && s[i] == '-')
        {
            printf("fu"); first = 0; continue;
        }
        int j = s[i] - '0';
        if(first == 0) printf(" ");
        if(first == 1) first = 0;
        printf("%s",table[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}




You use scanf() instead of fgets(). Thanks for your answer but it's seems like not what I want.

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
